# Are breadcrumbs necessary on the home page?

Tags: homepage, breadcrumbs

Our SAAS product uses breadcrumbs throughout the platform to improve user navigation.

However, I'm wondering if it is necessary to display breadcrumbs on the start / home page that the user lands on since it will only show the current level (Home) they are on?

I can't think of any reason why I should display the breadcrumbs on the Homepage, are there any?

Comment: They're probably not necessary on the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

Breadcrumbs are absolutely necessary for most website.

But you are correct, they are not needed on the homepage and I cannot think of any reason for it.

References for considerations:
https://vwo.com/blog/why-use-breadcrumbs/

Comment: Do you think that breadcrumbs are necessary for *this* website for example?